# Nested CollectionType - One form to create multiple entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, twig, symfony4

I'd really appreciate any help with this. I've had a look at the CollectionType's doc's but I can't see anything that refers to my particular case, and I can't find much documentation on nested CollectionType's.

In my "new customer" form, I want to be able to create a customer with ONE phone and at the same time create ONE contact who will also have ONE phone.

The below *works* except for the phone for the contact.

**CustomerController**

```
/**
 * @Route("/new", name="customer_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function new(Request $request): Response
{
    $customer = new Customer();

    $phone = new Phone();
    $customer->getPhones()->add($phone);

    $contact = new Contact();
    $customer->getContacts()->add($contact);

    $form = $this->createForm(CustomerType::class, $customer);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($customer);
        $entityManager->persist($phone);
        $entityManager->persist($contact);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('customer_show', [
            'customer' => $customer,
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('customer/new.html.twig', [
        'customer' => $customer,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

**Customer**

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Contact", mappedBy="customer")
 */
private $contacts;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Phone", mappedBy="customer")
 */
private $phones;
```

**Contact**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $firstName;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Customer", inversedBy="contacts")
 */
private $customer;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Phone", mappedBy="contact")
 */
private $phones;
```

**Phone**

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $value;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Customer", inversedBy="phones")
 */
private $customer;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Contact", inversedBy="phones")
 */
private $contact;
```

**CustomerType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('phones', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => PhoneType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
            'allow_add' => true,
        ])
        ->add('contacts', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => ContactType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
            'allow_add' => false,
        ])
    ;
}
```

**ContactType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstName')
        ->add('phones', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => PhoneType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
            'allow_add' => true,
        ])
    ;
}
```

**PhoneType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('value')
        ->add('status', HiddenType::class, [
            'data' => '0',
        ])
    ;
}
```

**_form.html.twig**
    {{{ form_start(form) }}

```
{{ form_label(form.name, 'Name') }}
{{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

{{ form_label(form.phones[0], 'Phone') }}
{{ form_widget(form.phones[0].value, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
{{ form_widget(form.phones[0].status, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

{{ form_label(form.contacts[0].firstName, 'First name') }}
{{ form_widget(form.contacts[0].firstName, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

// How do I display the phone for the contact?
```

Comment: have you tried also explicitly adding the phone to the contact via `$contact->getPhones()->add(new Phone());`? (I don't like that contact/customer expose the collection via getPhones, but that is besides the point...) after that it's just the same as `firstName`

Comment: That works. If you don't mind me asking - which approach would you take for a case like this?

Comment: for exposing collections: it's a preference on how to design interfaces. I would prefer adding `add{Subentity}` and `remove{Subentity}` methods such as `addPhone` etc. to modify the collections (it's a question of which interface you want to provide). iirc doctrine recommends using the existing collection. giving the collection to the outside and supposedly accepting another collection via `setPhones` could break functionality, which the add/remove approach wouldn't even allow. However, providing a collection is fairly *standard* and if other developers behave nicely ... it won't matter much

Comment: the `allow_add` functionality of forms requires *additional* javascript to work properly. if there is no entry in a collection, there might only be an empty container, where the entries are supposed to end up. adding an entry artificially (as I proposed) isn't the cleanest solution, but an acceptable one. there is a tutorial on how to achieve dynamic collections with adding/removing, also, forms have some `empty_data` setting (see https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/use_empty_data.html). It's mostly about separation of concerns. Should the controller worry about what form/entity require?